@RowKey griddb index for Timezone
Can I store the timestamp format for my time series container as a Long epoch and utilize the epoch value when executing sampling queries like TIMESTAMP('" + longEpoch + "') instead of employing the string format ('2004-02-05T10:15:30.000Z')?
The reason is I need to use UTC epoch format when working with time so it is less confusing and less error prone.
Additionally, when storing data as Date originTimestamp, which time zone does the database employ?

You seem to have repeated the text of your Question. Confusing.

Each to their taste. A count of seconds or milliseconds since the epoch doesn’t tell me anything and tends to confuse me more than the ISO 8601 format you mention that includes date and time of day in UTC.
